# Remoting request invalid for your session error for just one machine

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

One of our testers is getting this error when doing a javascript remoting call:

> Visualforce Remoting Exception: Remoting request invalid for your
>   session.

But interesting part is I used the same login to operate on the same VF page and on the same record but got no issue at all. And we are both using Chrome.

I googled this error message and all the existing information it is due to CSRF protection. But if that is the case, I guess it shouldn't behave differently on two machines? Is there anything to do with the browser settings etc. ?

Comment: If it helps, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11759

Answer (score 1):

We just helped him resolving the issue by closing all the chrome windows and reopen. As he is using a chrome plugin called multi-login, we guess it should be something wrong with the session info, not the code.